# How to move C: partition to another disk?

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I've got a little problem about Windows partitions -.-

I once installed Windows 11 on a SSD, and so far so good. Then, I tried to install some Linux distributions on another SSD, and here came the problems.

I made some mistakes, so I decided to remove Linux and just leave Windows, and now there is the C: partition on one SSD, and the EFI partition on the other one...

[image]

How can I move C: to the other SSD without neither reinstalling nor losing my files?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one procedure to do it:

- Create on a USB disk the
  [Windows installation media](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html)
  or alternatively a
  [Recovery drive](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4200-create-recovery-drive-windows-10-a.html)
- Install
  [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
- Run AOMEI and clone the `C:` partition on Disk 2 into the
  unallocated space on Disk 1, as described in
  [How to Perform Partition or Volume Clone Easily](https://www.ubackup.com/help/partition-or-volume-clone.html)
- Open up the computer and physically disconnect Disk 2
- Boot from the Windows installation media or the Recovery drive and do
  [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
- Try to reboot from disk. If it works, reconnect back Disk 2.

These operations can fail because of any one error in a way that
will prevent booting. To protect against it, use AOMEI to backup
your entire Disk 1 to USB and also
[Create AOMEI Bootable CD/DVD/USB Based on Windows PE](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html)
to be able to boot from it and return Disk 1 to its starting state.
Test that you can boot from it.

The count of USBs is now three. If this is a problem, you may
economize one USB by doing the Disk 1 backup to a file residing
on one of the other USBs, so you only need two.